# MySQL Syntax Error when I try creating a function

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION TaxBracket (SalaryPT FLOAT)
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
    DECLARE TB FLOAT;
    IF SalaryPT*52>36400 THEN
    SET TB=0.4;
    ELSE
    SET TB=0.2;
    END IF;
    RETURN TB;
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Getting error code 1064, would be really helpful if someone can help me figure out where am I going wrong with the syntax

Comment: I don't think you need `DELIMITER` in Workbench.

Comment: Your code compiles in MySQL 5.7 : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g1ukQcC6N3cHK4PfMX3her/0. In MySQL 8.0 you need the `NO SQL` or `DETERMINISTIC` keyword though: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g1ukQcC6N3cHK4PfMX3her/1

Comment: @GMB the NO SQL solved the problem thanks!